# ASP.NET MVC [FromForm] - Map into a record with different property names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I guess this can be a pretty good question, however I have a feeling that the answer can be also pretty much simple.

So, let's suppose I have a HTTP POST endpoint which receives from an external source a **form** in the payload.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyExample([FromForm] ExampleModel formModel)
```

My external source does not follow any standard naming convention, therefore, I can't rely on a simple equivalent "SerializerOptions".
So, the solution now would be manually set the property name I'm receiving.

If I have a record **ExampleModel**, how could I set the property tag so that **MVC [FromForm]** magic mapping could handle it?

```
public record ExampleModel([property: ????] string MyProperty)
```

I can create a specific record or class with the exact name from the payload. That would be the easiest solution, but I'm trying to see if there is another way to not force my property to be wrongly named also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a [BindAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.bindattribute) with a `Prefix` matching the name of the corresponding input element on the form.

Below example shows how the input value of a textbox named `OtherName` will be bound to `MyProperty` of the `ExampleModel`.

```
public record ExampleModel(
    [Bind(Prefix = "OtherName")] string MyProperty
    );

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="OtherName" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess both answers here are correct, I will try to perform a performance test to see which one is the fastest

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `[FromForm]` attribute to your record field definition like this:

```
public record ExampleModel([FromForm(Name="some nonstandard name with spaces")] string MyProperty)
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess both answers here are correct, I will try to perform a performance test to see which one is the fastest